# Bluemix WebsocketListener.Start: Error connecting to a doppler server

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

Has anyone faced this issue with Bluemix? One of my Bluemix instances crashes repeatedly and the log file shows the following error. Seems to be an internal error within Bluemix environment, and I could not understand the reason for it.
......

> 2016-08-04T12:02:07.617+0530[DEA/75]OUTStopped app instance (index 0) with guid 9b4ebc26-e5f9-4c61-a54e-f8c7437185a7
>   2016-08-04T12:02:17.783+0530[LGR/null]ERRWebsocketListener.Start: Error connecting to a doppler server
>   2016-08-04T12:02:17.799+0530[LGR/null]ERRproxy: error connecting to 158.85.134.172:8081: dial tcp 158.85.134.172:8081: getsockopt: connection refused
>   2016-08-04T12:02:17.899+0530[LGR/null]ERRproxy: error connecting to 158.85.134.172:8081: dial tcp 158.85.134.172:8081: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: Was this previously working?  There may have been some issues with the IoT Platform earlier today that affected some free orgs but have been resolved.  Let us know if you are still experiencing a problem and if so, what is your 6 character org ID?